# Is there an OrderBy option for ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I am trying to sort the items of a `ViewBag` list called via `ForEach`.

I see that there is a `Model.OrderBy` option.

Is there something similar for `ViewBag`?

My code is as follows:

```html
<select class="list-box tri-state" id="ParentID" name="ParentID">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.EmployeeList)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.FirstName @item.LastName</option>
    }
</select>
```

Ideally I would like the Selection list to be sorted by `FirstName`, `LastName`, but it is default sorting by `Id`.

How should I remedy this?

Comment: Your code is a really bad idea - no strong typed model binding, no client side validation, the selected item, will be lost if returning the view etc etc. Use use the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method to generate your `<select>`

Comment: I couldn't make the dropdownlistfor work with the concatenated firstname and lastname

Comment: That is simple to solve - `yourTable.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewBag` is dynamic.

So assuming it was set in the controller like

```
List<Employee> employees = getEmployeeList();

this.ViewBag.EmployeeList = employees;

//...

return View(model);
```

In the view, cast the property to a known type collection and the extension method should then be available.

```
@foreach (var item in (ViewBag.EmployeeList as List<Employee>)
    .OrderBy(_ => _.FirstName).ThenBy(_ => _.LastName)) {
      <option value="@item.Id">@item.FirstName @item.LastName</option>
}
```

Alternatively you can sort it in the controller before assigning it to the `ViewBag` as well and just have the code loop the collection in the view.

```
List<Employee> employees = getEmployeeList()
    .OrderBy(_ => _.FirstName).ThenBy(_ => _.LastName)
    .ToList();

this.ViewBag.EmployeeList = employees;

//...
```